# Restore a database but exclude certain indexes

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to exclude certain indices when restoring a database? I see that there is no option to do this in pg_restore, but I was hoping there may be some other way.

Comment: Create a list file from `pg_restore --list`, edit that file to comment out the indexes you want to omit, then run `pg_restore -L`. That's assuming your backup is in custom format of course.